# ¿Cómo hacer dos consultas en un mismo php?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Saludos, tengo una duda, tengo un archivo php en donde mando la consulta de una tabla, pero deseo hacer una busqueda filtrada en el mismo archivo. Tengo el siguiente código

```
<form name="BusquedaTrnasporte" method="POST">
<table>
    <td><h2>Placa del Vehiculo:<input type="text" size="20px" name="buscar"></h2></td>
    <td><center><button value="si" type="submit" class="botonok" name="btn"><span class="icon-eye"></span>Buscar</button></center></td>
    </table>
</form>
    <br><br>
<div>
    <center><table class="tb1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Placa</b></td>
            <td><b>Marca</b></td>
            <td><b>Modelo</b></td>
            <td><b>Tipo Vehiculo</b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php include('Secretaria/SelectTransporte.php'); ?>
</table>
```

En el php tengo el siguiente código

```
<?php 
    include('Conexion.php');

    $buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
    $btn = $_POST['btn'];

    if($btn == 'si'){
        $consulta = "select T.PLACA_TRANSPORTE, T.MARCA_TRANSPORTE, T.MODELO_TRANSPORTE, T.TIPO_TRANSPORTE from transporte T, estado E where T.ID_ESTADO = E.ID_ESTADO and T.PLACA_TRNASPORTE = '".$buscar."'";
    } else {
        $consulta = "select T.PLACA_TRANSPORTE, T.MARCA_TRANSPORTE, T.MODELO_TRANSPORTE, T.TIPO_TRANSPORTE from transporte T, estado E where T.ID_ESTADO = E.ID_ESTADO;";
    }

     echo $consulta;
    $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta)or die(mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 
    echo "<tr>
    <td>$row[0]</td>
    <td>$row[1]</td>
    <td>$row[2]</td>
    <td>$row[3]</td>
    </tr> \n"; 
}
mysqli_close($enlace);// Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
?>
```

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Si te refieres a tener dos posibilidades de consultas dependiendo de si hay o no datos en buscar lo puedes resolver con `isset($_POST['buscar'])...` consulta con criterio buscar, de lo contrario, consulta sin criterio buscar. Para dar seguridad al código usa consultas preparadas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió tu respuestas

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolver el problema de esa manera?